# Can I call the company overseeing my background check to explain information?

Tags: background-check

I accepted an offer contingent on background check. My résumé includes a job I do on the side without any official papers or payment - just part time work for a friend's company. All of that was clear and I wasn't hiding any of this information. My friend is listed as one of my references and I'm just fine if they call. I just dont want them to pull tax records, show I wasn't on their payroll and disqualify me.

Should I call the agency doing the background check to explain this?

Comment: If the agencies allowed the people being investigated to clarify anything that wasn't kosher, why would the employer ever trust them to do a proper background check? If the employer knows, then if something comes up with the agency doing the search, they will evaluate the results in the context of what you've told them. What exactly are you worried about if the company already knows and the background check will only confirm what you've told them?

Comment: Is the work for a mall company owned by your friend, or is it work that the company that employees your friend knows nothing about?

Comment: @jmac I've never done a background check, if you think I'm overthinking this and the consensus agrees please make that an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I do not understand what you're trying to ask

Comment: If they call the company to ask about your employment will they tell the investigator, "I have no idea who that person is?"

Comment: @mhoran_psprep no if they call the company I'm fine. I just dont know if these places usually call or just look at tax returns

Comment: I believe that makes you an independent contractor (by virtue of not being an employee) working pro bono. You might want to put that information on the resume so in the future people know what to expect

Comment: @Yamikuronue I do list it as (Remote) next to the city, and its clearly during the same time period as my full time job. But that is a good idea for next time - hopefully there wont be a next time though! I think of it more like an Internship

Comment: I know that at least in the US they won't be able to pull your tax records that information is private.  Your credit report, provided you have given them permission to run it, is not private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything you put on the resume and investigation forms should be verifiable. If they need more contact information they will ask for it before trying to do the investigation. If they find info that doesn't seem to match, they will ask for clarification.

Generally they will give you the opportunity to explain after the investigation, some times they make a mistake in the investigation, or they need help interpreting the info they find.

Example: they contacted the wrong company. I worked for a small company with a similar name, but they called the larger more well known company. Of course they never heard of me. This was easy to fix.

Example: Confusing financial info. A mortgage on an investment property was sold twice before they realized it was an investment property. So the two transactions were reversed, one of which was messed up because my check was already in the mail. The credit report was very confusing, it looked like I had several mortgages I never mentioned. It was easy to explain.

If you embellished your working relationship they could be concerned about what else you embellished. If you accepted payments without paying taxes on the income that could concern some employers.

Bottom line, over explain on the initial forms.

Comment: Okay then I should be fine. I didn't avoid taxes, I didn't collect any payment. I just do it on the side in exchange for the experience and to help my friend out